# VB.NET dynamic multi dimensional collections

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, dynamic, collections

as someone of you may know I'm a beginner in vb.net so I'd ask you a suggestion.

In VBA (I know it's a completely different language) my workaround often included arrays, and I could edit them in the middle of the code e.g.

```
Dim myArray() as String
```

and then modify it with

```
Redim Preserve (newDimension1, newDimension2)
```

But in VB.NET I can edit only the rightmost dimension and it limits the purpose for which I often use Arrays.
I discovered that ArrayLists are dynamic by default, so I can 'expand' them by simply using .add or .remove and it fits perfectly my needs but I read I cannot add more than one dimension (if I'm not wrong).

I also know something about Lists (which do not allow more than one dimension) and KeyValuePairs which are not dynamic at all and use only 2 dimensions.

I know it could sound too generic to many of you, but which collections could fit best my needs in this case? Are there some kind of multi dimensional dynamic lists/arrays/don't know what?

Thanks everybody for your answers and understanding.

**EDIT**

Although all your answers are really interesting (Olivier's one is really useful when dealing with dynamic variable's names) seems that vb shows one limit in its collections.

Regarding purposes, well it's generic since arrays (and collections in general) are very often used in OOLs and everyone use it for their own scope.

One of the reason I personally use it is to 'store' data - e.g. Excel ranges.

Everyone suggest not to use this classic method

```
dim myArray as Object(,) = CType(xlRange.Value, Object(,))
```

which indeed produces a 2d Array but in return has its own issues in terms of efficiency and conversion to other objects, so i was wondering if exists a 'cleaner' method to produce the same result in a more elegant way given unknown dimensions (I'm not really into tailor-made one use functions).

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't really a definitive answer to your question, so it's really too opinion-based. I will say that there are no collection types that fit your needs. If they will only be small then you could use 2D arrays and just write your own method to create a new array and copy the data across, which is what ReDim Preserve does anyway. Alternatively, use a DataTable, which allows you to add and remove columns and rows as desired.

Comment: You can have a List(Of List(Of ...)). It is often useful to have a List(Of SomeClass), and that class could have lists as (some of) its properties.

Comment: How about using List(Of List(Of String))?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List(Of List(Of String))`. But you will have to create inner lists for each entry of the outer list. Unlike arrays, where every position in the array can be accessed after the array was created, you must first add items to the list to make it grow.

```vb
' Create the list
Dim list = new List(Of List(Of String))()

' Add an empty inner list to the outer list
list.Add(new List(Of String)())

' Add elements to this inner list
list(0).Add("hello")
list(0).Add("world")

' Add a second inner list with a collection initializer
list.Add(New List(Of String) From {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"})

' Access an element
Dim s As String = list(1)(2) ' = "ccc"
```

But you can also combine other types of collections. E.g., you can create an array of arrays, also called jagged array, which is not the same as a 2D array. Or you can create an array of lists or a list of arrays.

You could even create a dictionary with a tuple as key. This is particularly advantageous when only a few index positions are occupied.

```vb
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of (Integer, Integer), String)()
dict((0, 0)) = "hello"
dict((0, 1)) = "world"
dict((1, 0)) = "aaa"
dict((1, 1)) = "bbb"
dict((1, 2)) = "ccc"

Dim s As String = dict((1, 2)) ' = "ccc"
```

In .NET there are virtually no limits on how you can combine types.

Comment: I'd say the main issue with a list of lists is that there's no proper columns. The inner lists are not constrained to have the same number of items and "adding a column" would require adding an item to each inner list. Those are not show stoppers but they're far from ideal.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, yes. We don't know the use case, therefore it is difficult to give a "best answer".